# Failed to connect to SignalR Hub when i set Android Options Linking => Sdk and User Assemblies

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, signalr.client

I am trying to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client in a Xamarin Forms project.
This [my project link](https://github.com/MohamedBnSaid/XamarinSignalRCore). It works fine in debug mode when Android Options => **Linking ="None"**.

[image: Work fine]

But, it doesn't work when i set Android Options => **Linking = "Sdk and User Assemblies"** [Sdk and User Assemblies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Fay.png) and I get this exception :

> System.FormatException: Invalid negotiation response received. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Client.HttpConnection+NegotiationResponse. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'connectionId', line 1, position 16.

[image: exception]

Comment: I have the same problem; using microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client (preview 1 final). Can anyone actually get this thing to work? Have not seen a single working example.

Comment: I have been able to get this working: https://github.com/radu-matei/signalr-samples, but be careful to use the exact same versions of .Net Core 2 (not Framework!) and alpha2 version of aspnetcore.signalr.client (do not use preview release!).